# Replacement SOAP Library/Class for VBA

Tags: vba, web-services, soap

Some time ago, Microsoft ended support for its VBA SOAP library and removed it from all of the Office products.

Does anyone know of a source for the old library or a replacement library or class?

Comment: Some links in this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e4f4d5f3-a2be-4b77-8e3e-e6c9dc6740e9/missing-reference-microsoft-office-soap-type-library-v30?forum=officegeneral

Comment: Unfortunately none of those help. The install package won't update Office 2016 and the other items require a Microsoft SOAP library.